# A seasonal SE raffle

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash, secret-hats

**All users that have been active in the month of December should be entered into a raffle to take place on New Year's Day**

Ideas for prizes include:

- a branded t-shirt
- a mug
- a donation to charity of choice
- signed picture of someone

Other aspects for discussion:

- overlay a raffle ticket number on user profiles
- live stream the raffle
- limit entry by rep>100
- weighting (of winning probability) by rep
- interaction with hat based thing

Comment: Hmmm a raffle for everyone who participates in this year's Winterbash event network-wide *would* be an interesting idea.

Comment: Only if I can get a signed picture of Jon Skeet for my Stack Overflow shrine.

Comment: **"weighting (of winning probability) by rep"** - a very nice way to rub even more salt on the wounds of those stuck contributing in low traffic sites.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist good point. Perhaps the weighting could be `rep/total_rep_awarded_on_site` `rep/site_traffic_metric` to adjust for that. Or just do away with the idea of weighting all together.

Comment: @atomh33ls that would probably be much more fair. That said, I prefer contest that have nothing to do with the site rep like the ones from the past years (see for example the Winterbash story one, the picture one for the "self powering UPS" memorial and so on) since I fear that anything tied to rep will just prompt some users to try to game the system even more

Comment: I'd love a SO Mug or TShirt. Especially a mug.